# Python : function definition keeps returning 'None' in the middle of the desired output

Tags: python

okay so i'm making code for my girlfriend for our 6th anniversary. 
I'm a complete noob to programming. I'm writing some very simple code to make, basically an input output machine of number inputs, in order for the user (her) to receive string outputs.

i keeps seeing "none" when i run my code. why? 
here goes.

```
def love(n):
  if n < 0 : 
    print "Why would it be negative?!" 
  if n == 0 : 
      print "well that is just hurtful" 
  if n == 1 :
    print "I REALLY love you" 
  if n == 2 : 
    print "You make me smile at least once, each and every day"
  if n == 3 : 
    print"you wouldn't believe how annoying it was to get this program to run properly! but it was worth it"
  if n == 4 : 
      print "let's " + "shoot a little higher than that"
  else:
    print "I honestly can't see myself without you anymore" 


print love(0) 

print "Wanna try again? :D "
```

Comment: i don't know why it came out formatted terribly either...

Comment: When creating a post there is the option to highlight blocks of code and click the "code block" option to have it formatted as code.

Comment: You can do what Snukus said and hit the _code_ button, or you can just indent all your code by 4 spaces—which is what I did when I edited your post.

Comment: replace `print love(0)` with `love(0)`

Comment: You could also replace all the `print` calls inside the `love` function with `return`s instead. That way, `love` will return a string, and you can print that string. This is a more modular solution since it allows you to do whatever you want with the message rather than being forced to immediately print it.

Answer (score 7):

```
love(0) # is all you need.
```

---

You dont need to call `print love()`, as you already have print statements within `love`. 
You are seeing `None` as `love` is doing all the work, and its not returning anything.

---

Also, you need to use a `if-elif-else` block in your function as you want only *one*, out of all of the print operations, to be run at a time.

```
if n < 0 : 
    print "Why would it be negative?!" 
elif n == 0 : 
      print "well that is just hurtful" 
elif n == 1 :
    print "I REALLY love you" 
elif n == 2 : 
    print "You make me smile at least once, each and every day"
elif n == 3 : 
    print"you wouldn't believe how annoying it was to get this program to run properly! but it was worth it"
elif n == 4 : 
      print "let's " + "shoot a little higher than that"
else:
    print "I honestly can't see myself without you anymore"
```

Although, beyond `2`, printing everything wouldn't hurt ;)

<sub>My 100<sup>th</sup> answer on SO ! Yay !</sub>

Comment: okay perfect! thanks. my other issue is why is the else statement always printing even though for ex. n==4 is true?

Comment: You need to make all the if statements after the first one "elif" instead of if. Other wise you're saying: if n isn't equal to 4, print what's in the else block.

Comment: ohhhhhhkay. i didn't know it worked like that. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your function has a default return value of `None`, so when you `print` it out, it will print `None`.

Simply call the function without the `print` statement.

Alternatively, you can replace all of the `print` statements in your function with `return`, and turn it into an `if-elif-else` block, since they're all mutually exclusive operations.  Then, printing `love(0)` will actually print out the return value.

Comment: Sheesh, talk about nitpicking. :P